# MySQL won't query to table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query I'm attempting to write to a certain table, I've tested this by taking out nearly almost all of the different values and variables and only left username wmy0 and wmy0t and it successfully queried, but now when I try to do all of this it doesn't query. And YES its a MUST to have all of these columns in my database.

Also is there any EASIER way to do this? if your wanting to know more about what I'm trying to accomplish you can visit

```
http://173.254.78.193/cash-flow-plan.php
```

to see the exact page I'm dealing with. Those are the inputs I'm attempting to insert in a table called `cash_flow_plan`. I am 100% certain it's a problem like.. I have an extra comma... or at the end of a number where it shouldn't be... but I have been looking, for hours... and I can't find it. So now I'm here trying to find a better solution to this.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (username, wmyt000, wmy1100t, wmy2000t, wmy0, wmy0t, wmy1, 
wmy1t, wmy2, wmy2t, wmy3, wmy3t, wmy4, wmy4t, wmy5, wmy5t, wmy6, wmy6t, wmy7, wmy7t, wmy8, 
wmy8t, wmy9, wmy9t, wmy10, wmy10t, wmy11, wmy11t, wmy12, wmy12t, wmy13, wmy13t, wmy14, 
wmy14t, wmy15, wmy15t, wmy16, wmy16t, wmy17, wmy17t, wmy18, wmy18t, wmy19, wmy19t, wmy20, 
wmy20t, wmy21, wmy21t, wmy22, wmy22t, wmy23, wmy23t, wmy24, wmy24t, wmy25, wmy25t, wmy26, 
wmy26t, wmy27, wmy27t, wmy28, wmy28t, wmy29, wmy29t, wmy30, wmy30t, wmy31, wmy31t, wmy32, 
wmy32t, wmy33, wmy33t, wmy34, wmy34t, wmy35, wmy35t, wmy36, wmy36t, wmy37, wmy37t, wmy38, 
wmy38t, wmy39, wmy39t, wmy40, wmy40t, wmy41, wmy41t, wmy42, wmy42t, wmy43, wmy43t, wmy44, 
wmy44t, wmy45, wmy45t, wmy46, wmy46t, wmy47, wmy47t, wmy48, wmy48t, wmy49, wmy49t, wmy50, 
wmy50t, wmy51, wmy51t, wmy52, wmy52t, wmy53, wmy53t, wmy54, wmy54t, wmy55, wmy55t, wmy56, 
wmy56t, wmy57, wmy57t, wmy58, wmy58t, wmy59, wmy59t, wmy60, wmy60t, wmy61, wmy61t, wmy62, 
wmy62t, wmy63, wmy63t, wmy64, wmy64t, wmy65, wmy65t, wmy66, wmy66t, wmy67, wmy67t, wmy68, 
wmy68t, wmy69, wmy69t, wmy70, wmy70t, wmy71, wmy71t, wmy72, wmy72t, wmy73, wmy73t, wmy74, 
wmy74t, wmy75, wmy75t, wmy76, wmy76t, wmy77, wmy77t, wmy78, wmy78t, wmy79, wmy79t, wmy80, 
wmy80t, wmy81, wmy81t, wmy82, wmy82t, wmy83, wmy83t, wmy84, wmy84t, wmy85, wmy85t, wmy86, 
wmy86t, wmy87, wmy87t, wmy88, wmy88t, wmy89, wmy89t, wmy90, wmy90t, wmy91, wmy91t, wmy92, 
wmy92t, wmy93, wmy93t, wmy94, wmy94t, wmy95, wmy95t, wmy96, wmy96t, wmy97, wmy97t, wmy98, 
wmy98t, wmy99, wmy99t, wmy100, wmy100t, wmy101, wmy101t, wmy102, wmy102t, wmy103, wmy103t, 
wmy104, wmy104t, wmy105, wmy105t, wmy106, wmy106t, wmy107, wmy107t, wmy108, wmy108t, wmy109, 
wmy109t, wmy110, wmy110t, wmy111, wmy111t, wmy112, wmy112t, wmy113, wmy113t, wmy114, wmy114t,
wmy115, wmy115t, wmy116, wmy116t, wmy117, wmy117t, wmy118, wmy118t, wmy119, wmy119t, wmy120, 
wmy120t, wmy121, wmy121t, wmy122, wmy122t, wmy123, wmy123t, wmy124, wmy124t, wmy125, wmy125t,
wmy126, wmy126t, wmy127, wmy127t, wmy128, wmy128t, wmy129, wmy129t, wmy130, wmy130t, wmy131, 
wmy131t, wmy132, wmy132t, wmy133, wmy133t, wmy134, wmy134t, wmy135, wmy135t, wmy136, wmy136t, 
wmy137, wmy137t, wmy138, wmy138t, wmy139, wmy139t, wmy140, wmy140t, wmy141, wmy141t, wmy142, 
wmy142t, wmy143, wmy143t, wmy144, wmy144t, wmy145, wmy145t, wmy146, wmy146t, wmy147, wmy147t, 
wmy148, wmy148t, wmy149, wmy149t, wmy150, wmy150t, wmy151, wmy151t, wmy152, wmy152t, wmy153, 
wmy153t, wmy154, wmy154t, wmy155, wmy155t, wmy156, wmy156t, wmy157, wmy157t, wmy158, wmy158t, 
wmy159, wmy159t, wmy160, wmy160t, wmy161, wmy161t, wmy162, wmy162t, wmy163, wmy163t, wmy164, 
wmy164t, wmy165, wmy165t, wmy166, wmy166t, wmy167, wmy167t, wmy168, wmy168t, wmy169, wmy169t, 
wmy170, wmy170t, wmy171, wmy171t, wmy172, wmy172t, wmy173, wmy173t, wmy174, wmy184t, wmy175, 
wmy175t, wmy176, wmy176t, wmy177, wmy177t, wmy178, wmy178t, wmy179, wmy179t, wmy180, wmy180t, 
wmy181, wmy181t, wmy182, wmy182t, wmy183, wmy183t, wmy184, wmy184t, wmy185, wmy185t, wmy186, 
wmy186t, wmy187, wmy187t, wmy188, wmy188t, wmy189, wmy189t, wmy190, wmy190t, wmy191, wmy191t, 
wmy192, wmy192t, wmy193, wmy193t, wmy194, wmy194t, wmy195, wmy195t, wmy196, wmy196t, wmy197, 
wmy197t, wmy198, wmy198t, wmy199, wmy199t, wmy200, wmy200t, wmy201, wmy201t, wmy202, wmy202t, 
wmy203, wmy203t, wmy204, wmy204t, wmy205, wmy205t, wmy206, wmy206t, wmy207, wmy207t, wmy208,
wmy208t, wmy209, wmy209t, wmy210, wmy210t, wmy211, wmy211t, wmy212, wmy212t, wmy213, wmy213t, 
wmy214, wmy214t, wmy215, wmy215t, wmy216, wmy216t, wmy217, wmy217t, wmy218, wmy218t, wmy219, 
wmy219t,wmy220, wmy220t, wmy221, wmy221t, wmy222, wmy222t, wmy223, wmy223t, wmy224, wmy224t, 
wmy225, wmy225t, wmy226, wmy226t, wmy227, wmy227t, wmy228, wmy228t, wmy229, wmy229t, wmy230, 
wmy230t) 



VALUES ('Aaron', '$_POST[wmyt000]', '$_POST[wmy1100t]', '$_POST[wmy2000t]', '$_POST[wmy0]',   
'$_POST[wmy0t]', '$_POST[wmy1]', '$_POST[wmy1t]', '$_POST[wmy2]', '$_POST[wmy2t]', '$_POST[wmy3]',    
'$_POST[wmy3t]', '$_POST[wmy4]', '$_POST[wmy4t]', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
NULL, NULL, '$_POST[wmy10]',  '$_POST[wmy10t]', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '$_POST[wmy20]', '$_POST[wmy20t]', 
'$_POST[wmy21]', '$_POST[wmy21t]', '$_POST[wmy22]', '$_POST[wmy22t]', '$_POST[wmy23]', '$_POST[wmy23t]', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '$_POST[wmy40]', '$_POST[wmy40t]', '$_POST[wmy41]', '$_POST[wmy41t]', '$_POST[wmy42]', '$_POST[wmy42t]', '$_POST[wmy43]', '$_POST[wmy43t]', '$_POST[wmy44]', '$_POST[wmy44t]', '$_POST[wmy45]', '$_POST[wmy45t]', '$_POST[wmy46]', '$_POST[wmy46t]', '$_POST[wmy47]', '$_POST[wmy47t]', '$_POST[wmy48]', '$_POST[wmy48t]', '$_POST[wmy49]', '$_POST[wmy49t]', '$_POST[wmy50]', '$_POST[wmy50t]', '$_POST[wmy51]', '$_POST[wmy51t]', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '$_POST[wmy60]', '$_POST[wmy60t]', '$_POST[wmy61]', '$_POST[wmy61t]', '$_POST[wmy62]', '$_POST[wmy62t]', '$_POST[wmy63]', '$_POST[wmy63t]', '$_POST[wmy64]', '$_POST[wmy64t]', '$_POST[wmy65]', '$_POST[wmy65t]', '$_POST[wmy66]', '$_POST[wmy66t]', '$_POST[wmy67]', '$_POST[wmy67t]', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '$_POST[wmy80]', '$_POST[wmy80t]', '$_POST[wmy81]', '$_POST[wmy81t]', '$_POST[wmy82]', '$_POST[wmy82t]', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,  '$_POST[wmy90]', '$_POST[wmy90t]', '$_POST[wmy91]', '$_POST[wmy91t]', '$_POST[wmy92]', '$_POST[wmy92t]', '$_POST[wmy93]', '$_POST[wmy93t]', '$_POST[wmy94]', '$_POST[wmy94t]', '$_POST[wmy95]', '$_POST[wmy95t]', '$_POST[wmy96]', '$_POST[wmy96t]', '$_POST[wmy97]', '$_POST[wmy97t]', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '$_POST[wmy110]', '$_POST[wmy110t]',  '$_POST[wmy111]', '$_POST[wmy111t]', '$_POST[wmy112]', '$_POST[wmy112t]', '$_POST[wmy113]', '$_POST[wmy113t]', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '$_POST[wmy130]', '$_POST[wmy130t]', '$_POST[wmy131]', '$_POST[wmy131t]', '$_POST[wmy132]', '$_POST[wmy132t]', '$_POST[wmy133]', '$_POST[wmy133t]', '$_POST[wmy134]', '$_POST[wmy134t]', '$_POST[wmy135]', '$_POST[wmy135t]', '$_POST[wmy136]', '$_POST[wmy136t]', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,  '$_POST[wmy150]', '$_POST[wmy150t]', '$_POST[wmy151]', '$_POST[wmy151t]', '$_POST[wmy152]', '$_POST[wmy152t]', '$_POST[wmy153]', '$_POST[wmy153t]', '$_POST[wmy154]', '$_POST[wmy154t]', '$_POST[wmy155]', '$_POST[wmy155t]', '$_POST[wmy156]', '$_POST[wmy156t]', '$_POST[wmy157]', '$_POST[wmy157t]', '$_POST[wmy158]', '$_POST[wmy158t]', '$_POST[wmy159]', '$_POST[wmy159t]', '$_POST[wmy160]', '$_POST[wmy160t]', '$_POST[wmy161]', '$_POST[wmy161t]', '$_POST[wmy162]', '$_POST[wmy162t]', '$_POST[wmy163]', '$_POST[wmy163t]', '$_POST[wmy164]', '$_POST[wmy164t]', '$_POST[wmy165]', '$_POST[wmy165t]', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '$_POST[wmy170]', '$_POST[wmy170t]', '$_POST[wmy171]', '$_POST[wmy171t]', '$_POST[wmy172]', '$_POST[wmy172t]', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '$_POST[wmy190]', '$_POST[wmy190t]', '$_POST[wmy191]', '$_POST[wmy191t]', '$_POST[wmy192]', '$_POST[wmy192t]', '$_POST[wmy193]', '$_POST[wmy193t]', '$_POST[wmy194]', '$_POST[wmy194t]', '$_POST[wmy195]', '$_POST[wmy195t]', '$_POST[wmy196]', '$_POST[wmy196t]', '$_POST[wmy197]', '$_POST[wmy197t]', '$_POST[wmy198]', '$_POST[wmy198t]', '$_POST[wmy199]', '$_POST[wmy199t]', '$_POST[wmy200]', '$_POST[wmy200t]', '$_POST[wmy201]', '$_POST[wmy201t]', '$_POST[wmy202]', '$_POST[wmy202t]', '$_POST[wmy203]', '$_POST[wmy203t]', '$_POST[wmy204]', '$_POST[wmy204t]', '$_POST[wmy205]', '$_POST[wmy205t]', '$_POST[wmy206]', '$_POST[wmy206t]', '$_POST[wmy207]', '$_POST[wmy207t]', '$_POST[wmy208]', '$_POST[wmy208t]', '$_POST[wmy209]', '$_POST[wmy209t]', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

if you see where I have the NULL values set, its because I am not using that on the input page at the moment. (But will use it later so I need them)

Comment: Have you tried mysql_error to figure out what MySQL thinks is wrong?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: You have a million possible SQL injections. What do you mean 'it doesnt query'? Do you have error messages? What does `mysql_error()` tells you?

Comment: take a look at mint.com - just maybe you can gain some ideas, also for design :)

Comment: `echo` the SQL and paste it into PHPMyAdmin (or your Database-Admin-Tool) to check if it is valid.

Comment: Please use a different table to store the weekly/monthly/yearly data. I know you said you have to do it this way, but please consider this. I'm begging you :)

Comment: alexn, im pretty sure its real.. i posted it.. am i corerect? If you wanna get smart go somewhere else. 
@MathieuImbert , i dont care about sql injections. And im not sure, how to i debug PHP? What are some best practices to debug?

Helmut i like my design, thank you though... O.o 

Is today lets post stupid random comments that are no help to the poster day or what?

WouterH i see your concern , but im trying to stay organized with this and if you knew exactly how the application works you would disadgree with yourself jsut as i am.

Comment: @AaronRussell I just told you how to debug. Use `mysql_eror()`. And I strongly advise you to read about SQL injections, even if you 'don't care about them'. Do you realize that you just posted a very unsecure piece of code along with the form. And that anyone with bad intents, and a little knowledge can ruin your database?

Comment: @MathieuImbert its not that i dont care, its that i dont care right now. I will take care of it once i figure out my little problems first. As far as error goes, i got it to tell me that wmy184t was enetered twice so i fixed that. And now its saying successfull

Answer (score 2):

I copied the code into an IDE and found no syntax errors. The only thing that I can suggest is that you have a blank variable in your code upon time of execution. My suggestion is to do an `echo $sql;` just prior to running the query - and look for something that looks like `, '',` in the values section.

The better way would be to use PDO and a prepared statement - probably along with named placeholders along the lines of:

```
insert into $tbl_name (col1, col2) values (:col1, :col2)
```

where you can avoid injection attacks and also use the `bind->` on each paramater before adding it - which means you *should* be forced to validate each one before you bind it.

Answer (score 0):

echo the query and then run the Program, then copy the query you are trying to execute and paste it in the mysql prompt I think this will help you to find where the problem exactly exists...